# Plone automatic content generation following folder generation

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I was asked to implement the following on my Plone installation:

> After a user created a new folder, he should be forwarded to the
>   creation of a new page which should then be the default view of the
>   folder.

I tried to achieve that using content rules, but unfortunately such behavior is not supported there.

What is your suggestion of achieving that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be a solution for your Problem

Define an Eventhandler in events.py

```
def notifyFolderIsAdded(folder, event):
    folder.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(folder.absolute_url() + "/++add++Document")
```

Register the EventHandler in configure.zcml

```
<subscriber
   for="plone.app.contenttypes.interfaces.IFolder
        zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent"
   handler=".events.notifyFolderIsAdded" />
```

Look at [Events](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/events.html) and [Event Handlers](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/event-handlers.html) in Plone Docs.

Comment: This is half of what OP is looking for.  Redirecting to an add form does not add the document without additional manual step, and does not set as default view of the folder.

I am also unsure about doing this for ALL folders.  Supposing @waynebird wants all this done on a special *type* of folder, it would make more sense to have any event handler registered to just one specific kind of folder.

Also possible to use subscribers with content rules, provided a custom action (e.g. mark a folder with marker interface based on some criteria, then subscriber takes over on the heavy lifting).

Comment: ok, in the eventhandler it can be added the document with the id and title of the Folder (per Definition: the Title of Folder is the Title of Document). and then set the default Page of Folder via folder.setDefaultPage("id_of_document").

Comment: Well, thank you for your suggestion so far. It looks like it will help me a great deal with my prooblem. I just need some clarification: I have a lot of eventy.py and configure.zcml files in my buildout. Which one are you talking about?
or do I have to create my own Product like the example on the events page of the documentation?

Comment: You must write your own package. It is insignificant how the file, with the Eventhandler is named.  Important is the notation in the subscriber directive: handler=".name_of_file.name_of_handler". in the example it is events.py with notifyFolderIsAdded

Comment: Hi, thank you for your clarification. It works as you intended! So today learned not only how to register an event handler but also how to make a Plone addon. What a day!
What is still missing: After the user saves  the page (manually, this is intended), the default view is set to that page. This should also work with an event handler I think?
@sdupton: actually this shall happen after every folder creation, as wanted by the customer. I'm looking forward for the first complaints and the task to change it back :D

Comment: Yes, so is it. Register the Eventhandler for IDocument and all is fine. Happy Plone coding!

Comment: @Waynebird there are certainly folks in the Plone community who dislike the folder vs. page distinction and the way we solve it with default pages.  Having a folder that is automatically also like a page (with the mirage you are creating) is not unreasonable, but it is imperfect (sometimes it is nice to just have a folder that does not obligate page content; and there is no view AFAICT to create a hybrid of a page and something like the listing views for folders, unless you make a collection the default item instead of a page).

Comment: @sdupton Good that you mention it, my example regards that, updated my answer.

Comment: So I tired to add an eventhandler on the creation of a document similar to the one for the folder:
`def notifyDocumentIsAdded(document, event):`
The idea is to get the folder of the document and then call folder.setDefaultPage(document). Is this promising? Unfortunately I don't know yet how to get the parent folder of my document.

Comment: Getting the Parent is in the Docs here: http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/reference/manipulating-content-objects.html#getting-the-objects-parent-folder
Please Check that the Parent-Folder is empty, this is the Use-Case for adding the first Document. Note the Eventhandler for IDocument runs on every Document Adding in Folder!

Answer (score 3):

Create a new content-type, being a clone of a Folder, extended by a rich-text-field. Here's a working Archetypes-based example:
https://github.com/ida/adi/tree/master/adi.subsection

It ships with two view-templates, one showing only the text-field, the other showing the text-field *and* a list of the item's children.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Ida's idea is a good solution that your customer might go for. It's quite quick to do it Dexterity when you know how.

We will do the following:

- add a Rich Text field to the original Folder type (or a Clone of the Folder type if you prefer) via the RichText behavior
- allow that Folder type to use `document_view` - a view normally used just by Pages/Documents.
- default the Folder type to use that `document_view`

Add the following to your Plone addon at `my.addon/my/addon/profiles/default/types/Folder.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="Folder" meta_type="Dexterity FTI" i18n:domain="plone"
   xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n">

  <!-- View information -->
  <property name="default_view">document_view</property>
  <property name="view_methods" purge="False">
    <element value="document_view" />
  </property>

  <property name="behaviors" purge="False">
    <element value="plone.app.contenttypes.behaviors.richtext.IRichText"/>
  </property>

</object>
```

Then stick this in any `configure.zcml` (I used the one in the browser folder, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter) in the same addon:

```
<configure package="plone.app.contenttypes.browser">
  <browser:page
      name="document_view"
      for="plone.app.contenttypes.interfaces.IFolder"
      template="templates/document.pt"
      layer="plone.app.contenttypes.interfaces.IPloneAppContenttypesLayer"
      permission="zope2.View"
      menu="plone_displayviews"
      title="View as Document"
      />
</configure>
```

The issue with taking things this way, is if the customer wants to revert things to normal Plone behaviour, then they will need to copy the Rich Text out of every Folder into a new Page.

By the way you can set `purge="False"` for the `view_methods` property in `Folder.xml` to stop users selecting any other view for Folders.

Answer (score 2):

There's an app for that ;)

There's a 3rd-party content rule that allows you to set the default view. Just add [sc.contentrules.layout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sc.contentrules.layout) to your buildout.

Additionaly, you may add another package to allow Python scripting actions through the web (in order to redirect user to Document creation). There are two options, not sure whether they are updated:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.contentrules.runscript/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.ruleactions.pythonscript

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the sc.contentrules.layout, but whenever I try to add a Layout option to a content rule in the web interface I get an error:
NotImplementedError: The class deriving from AutoExtensibleForm must have a 'schema' property

Comment: @Waynebird, are u running Plone 5? The product wasn't yet migrated but you could [open an issue](https://github.com/simplesconsultoria/sc.contentrules.layout/issues/new) in order to help that process.